# Вылетает ошибка при запуске новой активности Android

Tags: android

Немогу понять в чем ошибка. При нажатии на кнопку, которая запускает новую активность на реальном Galaxy 5x - приложение останавливается. Вроде все на месте : файл манифест, созданы xml и .java. Ошибки в не подсвечиваются.

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button next;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }});


    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Пётр on 07.08.2016.
 */
public class IntentActivity extends Activity {
Button cencel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cencel);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intentactivity);


        cencel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onDestroy();
            }});


    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ivarious.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".IntentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.ivarious.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Firsht Activity"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next Activity"
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="132dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

Не знаю где и какая, в телефоне выбивает сообщение "приложение остановлено " и все....у меня эмулятор не работает из-за каких то настроек биос...но в окне состояния еще есть строки

```
08-08 11:30:04.879 10082-10082/com.ivarious.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ivarious.myapplication, PID: 10082
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.ivarious.myapplication.IntentActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3913)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3860)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4184)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4152)
    at com.ivarious.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:23)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Вы не сообщили о том где и какая ошибка возникает. Без этого вам помочь невозможно. На 95% у вас NPE

Comment: Button cencel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cencel);
попробуйте эту строку в  onCreate() занести

Comment: и попробуйте сделать Build -> Clean Project  и Build -> Rebuild Project и у вас наверное Instant Run Включен

Comment: ответ в ошибке: Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? Возможно, вы забыли указать активити в АндроидМанифест файле